# How to Use Web Services in Android Application?

Tags: android

I am creating an application in which I want to access a web service and perform a particular task like if I enter the two number into the edit Text and click on the button the addition or subtraction or whatever shows on to the screen. and I do not want to use the local database of Android.

Means my back-end process or say logic's are already created in SQl Sever. But I don't know how to call or access the functionality of web services in Android. Please Help me Out.

Thanks in Advance for Any Help........

Comment: in search box type this [android]+web service , you will get useful result. You should search for the question before posting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amit you haven't searched well on google for this because if you did so you didn't ask this question here.There are lot of tutorial for this on net if let yourself search on net.Anyways i am posting the code snippet to demonstrate that how you can call the webservice from android...This code is to call only SOAP webservice.To call other webservices like JSON,REST etc search yourself on net.

**CODE:-**

```
public class HelloWebService extends Activity{

    String SOAP_ACTION="http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld";
    String METHOD_NAME = "HelloWorld";
    String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    String URL = "http://192.168.1.15:80/himanshu/helloworldwebservice.asmx";
    String SUM_SOAP_ACTION="http://tempuri.org/AddNumbers";
    String METHOD_NAME1 = "AddNumbers";

    TextView tv1,tv2,tv3,tv4,tv5;
    EditText etA,etB,etName;
    Button bt,dis;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.hello);

        etName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et);
        tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        tv3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv3);
        tv4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv4);
        tv5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv5);
        etA = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editA);
        etB = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editB);
        bt =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
        dis = (Button)findViewById(R.id.display);

        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                sum();
            }
        });

        dis.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Hello();    
            }
        });

    }

    public void Hello(){

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        Log.d("request", request.toString());

        String str = etName.getText().toString();
        Log.d("str", str);

        request.addProperty("name", str);
        Log.d("request", request.toString());

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        Log.d("envelope", envelope.toString());
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        Log.d("envelope", envelope.toString());
        HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        aht.debug=true;
        Log.d("aht", aht.toString());

        try
        {
            aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive results = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            Log.d("result", results.toString());
            tv1.setText(""+results.toString());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            tv2.setText(e.getClass().toString());
            Log.d("Error",e.getClass().toString());
        }

    }

    public void sum(){

            SoapObject sum_request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME1);
            Log.d("sum_request", sum_request.toString());

            //PropertyInfo pro1 = new PropertyInfo();
            String strA = etA.getText().toString();
            String strB = etB.getText().toString();
            sum_request.addProperty("a", strA);
            sum_request.addProperty("b", strB);

            Log.d("sum_request", sum_request.toString());

            SoapSerializationEnvelope sum_envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            Log.d("sum_envelope", sum_envelope.toString());

            sum_envelope.dotNet = true;
            sum_envelope.setOutputSoapObject(sum_request);
            Log.d("sum_envelope", sum_envelope.toString());

            HttpTransportSE sum_aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            sum_aht.debug=true;
            Log.d("sum_aht", sum_aht.toString());

            try
            {
                sum_aht.call(SUM_SOAP_ACTION, sum_envelope);
                SoapPrimitive sum_results = (SoapPrimitive)sum_envelope.getResponse();
                Log.d("sum_result", sum_results.toString());
              //  int in = Integer.parseInt(sum_results.getProperty(0).toString());
                tv3.setText(""+sum_results.toString());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                tv3.setText(e.getClass().toString());
                Log.d("sum_error", e.getClass().toString());
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your sample code himanshu it helps me lot to understands how it works actually. And Yes I Haven't try to search for it before But I have do a lots of searching for that I found lots of tutorial as well. Thanks a Ton again for helping.

Comment: http://10.10.206.105/Webservicetest/service.asmx  This is the my web service URl But I am getting an error                             03-29 13:29:38.912: W/dalvikvm(574): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 37 (Lorg/ksoap2/serialization/SoapObject;) in Lcom/edu/WebActivity/FirstWebActivity;   Help me out plz what is the problem

Comment: have you added the ksoap2 library in ur project if not get it from here..http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/ and learn urself how to add it on ur project from net.Best of luck....

Comment: I have added the the latest ksoap2 jar file ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar even though it will give me this error

Comment: post ur FirstWebActivity code...

Comment: why u put this code in comment buddy.Go to ur question and edit that and put the code there.

Comment: By mistake it will happen SORRY... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923425/regot-an-error-while-using-web-service              This is the link where i have posted the my FirstwebActivity code line. HELP ME OUT.

Answer (score 1):

Try Googling first about using webservice in android similar to the below concept. Currency coverting using google's webservice `http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=150GBP=?USD` This link will convert the `150 British pound as US Dollars` using below code -

```
String url = "http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=150GBP=?USD";
String cost = getResponse(url);
```

*getResponse*

```
private String getResponse (String url)
{
    HttpEntity entity = null;
    try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream is = entity.getContent();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
        String line="0";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Here, you can place your amount in currency instead of `150` and also dynamic input at run time. The String **Cost** provides the result from `Webservice`

This is an example for using a web-service in a simple way in android. You can modify this according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You should have URL to pass those two numbers to webservice. You need to parse that URL. Webservice will retrieve the result for calculation. Show me that URL, I can write code which may help you.

Comment: Please give me sample code for it.

Comment: Check out these links : (1) http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-build-a-simple-sax-parser/  (2) http://as400samplecode.blogspot.in/2011/11/android-parse-xml-file-example-using.html... You can get some idea from this. Else you can ask me.

Answer (score 0):

check for WSClient for android. here you can generate a jar file which can be used in your android application. follow this [link](http://wsclient.neurospeech.com/)

Answer (score 0):

What u have tried till now? Atleast you have to googled something and try then only we can help for you.

Anyway try the following link as follows

[AndroidJSON](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html)

[ReadJSON](http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parse-read-json-data-into-a-android-listview/)