# RE:Got an error while using Web service

Tags: android

```
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.AndroidHttpTransport;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;



public class FirstWebActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    String SOAP_ACTION="http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld";
    String METHOD_NAME = "HelloWorld";
    private static final String  SumsoapAction = "http://tempuri.org/add";
    private static final String  methodName = "add";
    private static final String UrlNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static final String URL = "http://10.10.206.105/Webservicetest/service.asmx";


    TextView tv1;
    EditText Ed1;
    EditText Ed2;@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Result);
        Ed1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstValue);
        Ed2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.SecondValue);

        SoapObject sum_request = new SoapObject(UrlNamespace, methodName);
        Log.d("sum_request", sum_request.toString());
        //PropertyInfo pro1 = new PropertyInfo();
        String strA = Ed1.getText().toString();
        String strB = Ed2.getText().toString();
        sum_request.addProperty("a", strA);
        sum_request.addProperty("b", strB);
        Log.d("sum_request", sum_request.toString());
        SoapSerializationEnvelope sum_envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        Log.d("sum_envelope", sum_envelope.toString());
        sum_envelope.dotNet = true;        
    }
```

Comment: In above code i try to access the add method via webservice but i have getting an error on SoapObject initialization. and error is03-29 13:54:07.513: E/dalvikvm(630): Could not find class 'org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject', referenced from method com.edu.WebActivity.FirstWebActivity.Hello    
03-29 13:54:07.513: W/dalvikvm(630): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 37 (Lorg/ksoap2/serialization/SoapObject in Lcom/edu/WebActivity/FirstWebActivity; plz help me out to resolve this error

Comment: ur code formatting is wrong make it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey ur missing the following code:-

```
 try
      {
          sum_aht.call(SUM_SOAP_ACTION, sum_envelope);
          SoapPrimitive sum_results = (SoapPrimitive)sum_envelope.getResponse();
          Log.d("sum_result", sum_results.toString());
      //  int in = Integer.parseInt(sum_results.getProperty(0).toString());
          tv3.setText(""+sum_results.toString());
      }
       catch (Exception e)
         {
              tv3.setText(e.getClass().toString());
              Log.d("sum_error", e.getClass().toString());
            }
```

Comment: I know these try catch block are not shown onto the above code because i'm facing some problems for posting the whole code... And these line aleardy added in my application along with the some namespace like org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject, SoapEnvelopeetc. But facing a probvlem only on SoabObject class.

Comment: ok one thing i have to ask you here now.Do you have any experience working on android? Tell the truth its important.

Comment: no i dont have much experience but yes i am working on android since the oct 2011. but many times i have solved the many query by working on trying on it. But this one is little bit harder one.

Comment: ok you have to learn lot more.go for the below links....                                       http://p-xr.com/android-development-tutorial-reading-soap-services/  http://sarangasl.blogspot.in/2011/10/android-web-service-access-tutorial.html

Comment: SoapObject request = new SoapObect(Namsepace, Method); When i put my cursor on to SoapObject then it will shows The element has no attached javadoc and the javadoc could not be found in the attached source. now tell me what is the actual problem.

Comment: tell me the steps how you added ksoap.jar in ur project?

Comment: Right Click On Project --> Properties --> Java build path --> Libraries Tab --> Add External jar -->ok I have followed these steps

Comment: 03-30 12:06:20.955: E/dalvikvm(279): Could not find class 'org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject', referenced from method com.edu.WebActivity.FirstWebActivity.add
03-30 12:06:20.955: W/dalvikvm(279): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 37 (Lorg/ksoap2/serialization/SoapObject;) in Lcom/edu/WebActivity/FirstWebActivity;
03-30 12:06:20.965: D/dalvikvm(279): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0001
03-30 12:06:20.965: D/dalvikvm(279): VFY: dead code 0x0003-00b0 in Lcom/edu/WebActivity/FirstWebActivity;.add ()V
Here's the My LOg Cat

Comment: did follow the links which i have given to you.If not first go through them i hope you will find ur mistake.

Comment: I have tired it again but getting a same error again and again now tell what will I do....

Comment: May be ur webservice not working properly.I dont understand y u dont able to pull data from webservice.have u try this example http://sarangasl.blogspot.in/2011/10/android-web-service-access-tutorial.html it is working perfectly on my side.dont use ur webservice with the above example try with the webservice given in the example.

Comment: have you add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission> in ur menifest file?

Comment: error remains the same does not not found the javadoc from the attached source. dont know what to do .......

Comment: check this link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980002/problems-with-javadoc

Comment: himanshu sir, thanks for the link but i also try this almost 10 to 15 times since i have started woorking on webservice. but problem is remain the same....

Comment: the problem of not getting a javadoc not found from the source is resolved now but my log show the same error SoapObject clsss not found

Comment: 03-30 15:17:44.635: E/dalvikvm(415): Could not find class 'org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject', referenced from method com.edu.WebActivity.FirstWebActivity.Hello
03-30 15:17:44.635: W/dalvikvm(415): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 37 (Lorg/ksoap2/serialization/SoapObject;) in Lcom/edu/WebActivity/FirstWebActivity;
03-30 15:17:44.635: D/dalvikvm(415): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0001
03-30 15:17:44.676: D/dalvikvm(415): VFY: dead code 0x0003-00a6 in Lcom/edu/WebActivity/FirstWebActivity;.Hello ()V

03-30 15:17:52.524: E/AndroidRuntime(415): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: himanshu need to ask one thing i.e. my soapObject doesn't  able to create its instance of a class why is this happening?

Comment: I cant answer this question perfectly as i m sitting far from...keep trying buddy.Event i too got success after 3 days of hard work with webservices.

Comment: Thanks for your priceless help Himanshu. Now I'm able to work with web services.

Comment: One more thing need to ask you about application

Comment: One more thing need to ask you about application which is when i install my application on real android device then it will shows the as many icon of my App as I have Activities in my application for e.g. In my App I have three activity one for web service second one for web site or on for main Activity then after installation it show three icons with the App name one icon for full app, second icon for second activity and third one is for another activity. Please tell me how can resolve this problem.